# AuthorizeNet API check if merchant account allows recurring billing

Tags: authorize.net

I cannot find out if recurring billing is enabled/disabled. I was told that this setting can be changed to disable authorize.net to accept recurring transactions.

Looking for the API to check this setting, or if it exists because I cannot find it.

Comment: There is no API check to determine of this API is enabled. You're best bet is to make an API call to create a test subscription and see if you get an error telling you that it isn't enabled.

Comment: @JohnConde Good idea, thanks